# what is the equivalent of Matlab's typecast function in R / Python / Julia

Tags: python, r, matlab, julia

what is the equivalent of Matlab's `typecast` function in R? in Python? in Julia? The description of Matlab's typecast function is given here: [typecast](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html)

Example, in Matlab

```
X = uint32([1 255 256])
X =
           1         255         256

Y = typecast(X, 'uint8') # little endian
Y =
   1   0   0   0  255   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
```

Thanks

Please note: I am not looking for the R / Python / Julia equivalent of Matlab's `cast` function (for instance I'm not looking for `as.integer`, `as.character` in R)

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the answers for Julia / R / Python. StackOverflow allows me to select one answer, but I up voted all the answers.

Comment: There is none in `R`. I'm also really confused about when you'd want to use `typecast`. What are you trying to do with your data? The closest thing i can think of is `format`, but that will just print your data in a different way.

Comment: @ScottRitchie: Might want to clarify what language you mean there is none in, since the question asks about several languages.

Comment: There isn't a way to do that in Python, because Python types abstract away from details like the number of bits.  You might be able to finagle something with numpy.  Without any explanation of why you want to do that, I'm as confused as Scott Ritchie is about what the point of that operation is.

Comment: I've clarified my comment about language.

Comment: You could probably create your own `typecast` function, that simply stores multiple representations of the same object in a class structure.

Comment: @BrenBarn -- I suppose you could rig something up using a combination of `struct.pack` and `struct.unpack`.  But you're point is well made.

Comment: This should probably be a Community Wiki, not a question, as there's no one right answer to this, given you're asking for answers in several different languages.

Comment: @ScottRitchie, I wanted to experiment with my own custom data serialization. I have 0.5 Tb of data that is mostly numeric with some strings and I need to run a lot of simulations (read data, save outputs). More than speed, I have a size issue. A lot of common serialization worry about complex data classes but not so much about size. I wanted to primarily convert strings into numbers and then write out a compressed binary file. I like HDF5 and R's RData and wanted to see if I can do better with my own format (and preferably a format that I can use across a lot of languages).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Python/Numpy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([1,255,256], dtype=np.int32)
>>> y = x.view(np.uint8)
```

(You could similarly change the type of `x` itself: `x.dtype = np.uint8`).

The output:

```
>>> x
array([  1, 255, 256])
>>> y
array([  1,   0,   0,   0, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   1,   0,   0], dtype=uint8)
```

Note that `y` is an **in-place** reinterpreted [view](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html) of `x`, so any changes in `y` will be reflected in `x`:

```
>>> y[:] = 255
>>> x
array([-1, -1, -1])
```

---

### MATLAB

Here is the equivalent MATLAB output:

```
>> x = int32([1,2,3])
x =
           1           2           3
>> y = typecast(x, 'uint8')
y =
    1    0    0    0    2    0    0    0    3    0    0    0

>> y(:) = 255
y =
  255  255  255  255  255  255  255  255  255  255  255  255
>> xx = typecast(y, 'int32')
xx =
          -1          -1          -1
```

If you want typecasting without creating deep copies in MATLAB, see [`typecastx`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17476-typecast-and-typecastx-c-mex-functions) MEX-function (which uses undocumented functionality to create shared data copies).

---

Beware that MATLAB uses [saturation arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturation_arithmetic), unlinke Python which has [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic):

#### Python/Numpy

```
# wraps around the other end
>>> np.array(257, dtype=np.uint8)
array(1, dtype=uint8)
```

#### MATLAB

```
% saturates at the maximum
>> uint8(257)
ans =
  255
```

Answer (score 11):

In Julia you're looking for **reinterpret**:

```
julia> X = Uint32[1,255,256]
3-element Array{Uint32,1}:
 0x00000001
 0x000000ff
 0x00000100

julia> Y = reinterpret(Uint8,X)
12-element Array{Uint8,1}:
 0x01
 0x00
 0x00
 0x00
 0xff
 0x00
 0x00
 0x00
 0x00
 0x01
 0x00
 0x00
```

Note however that for a matrix, even if the first dimension is singleton, you need to specify the resulting dimension (since it's ambiguous whether you want a 4x3 or a 1x12 Array):

```
julia> X = Uint32[1 255 256]
1x3 Array{Uint32,2}:
 0x00000001  0x000000ff  0x00000100

julia> Y = reinterpret(Uint8,X) # This won't work
ERROR: result shape not specified

julia> Y = reinterpret(Uint8,X,(1,12))
1x12 Array{Uint8,2}:
 0x01  0x00  0x00  0x00  0xff  0x00  0x00  0x00  0x00  0x01  0x00  0x00
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with multi-dimensional arrays? `Uint32[1,255,256]` but with `Uint32[[1 1], [1, 1]]` ?

Answer (score 7):

In R, you can write objects to a raw binary connection and get back a vector of bytes. That will get you the equivalent of your `uint8` output example:

```
> X=c(1,255,256)
> mode(X)
[1] "numeric"
```

The important thing here is the storage mode, not the mode. So we'll set it to integer - that's the equivalent of uint32, ie 4 bytes per integer:

```
> storage.mode(X)
[1] "double"
> storage.mode(X)="integer"
```

Now we can use `writeBin`. The second argument is an arbitrary raw vector, so we create one ad hoc with length zero. We only care about the return value:

```
> Xraw = writeBin(X,raw(0))
> Xraw
 [1] 01 00 00 00 ff 00 00 00 00 01 00 00
```

Do the reverse using `readBin`:

```
> readBin(Xraw,"int",n=3)
[1]   1 255 256
```

Unpack the first 8 bytes into a double:

```
> Xdoub = readBin(Xraw,"double",n=1)
> Xdoub
[1] 5.411089e-312
```

obviously is a nonsense value. But lets check its the same first 8 bytes:

```
> writeBin(Xdoub,raw(0))
[1] 01 00 00 00 ff 00 00 00
```

R doesn't really have all the C level types, so if you need anything you can either build it from raw bytes or write some C code to link with an R function.