# Equivalent Python function for MATLAB typecast function

Tags: python, matlab, casting

I have an array `Data` with size `[1,34]`.

Using MATLAB to convert this size array to a 8-bit unsigned integer array results in the following:

```
>> typecast(size(Data), 'uint8') 
>> 0    0    0    0    0    0  240   63    0    0    0    0    0    0   65   64
```

I tried the following in Python:

```
>> x = np.array([1,34],dtype = np.int64)
>> x.view(np.uint8)
>> array([ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 34,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
      dtype=uint8)
```

These are clearly not the same. How can I get the same result, and I would greatly appreciate the reasoning behind the MATLAB result too.

I took reference from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20931295/what-is-the-equivalent-of-matlabs-typecast-function-in-r-python-julia) answer too.

Answer (score 2):

The MATLAB code `size(Data)` returns a double-precision floating-point array, which is the default type for MATLAB.

The equivalent in Python should be:

```py
x = np.array([1,34], dtype=np.double)
x.view(np.uint8)
```